# Show that a conformal map of an open disk onto any open disk is necessarily bilinear.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that a conformal map of an open disk onto an open disk is necessarily bilinear. Please help me with this proof. Any help will be appreciated.

To clarify this, it's not just a map from a open disk to itself but to any open disk. By bilinear, I mean bilinear transformation, which is of the form $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. I think it's also called linear fractional transformation or Möbius transformation.

I am using [this book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Complex_Variables.html?id=SFqbV3i3hO0C). I don't know much about geometry. I learned that bilinear transformation can map a circle to any circle, which I feel will be useful for this proof.

Comment: If it fixes the origin then one of the big theorems says it's linear.

Comment: Rather than "bilinear", don't you mean "linear fractional" or "Mobius"? (And, indeed, as @DavidC.Ullrich comments, after you use a linear fractional transformation to assume wolog that the thing fixes the origin, Schwarz' Lemma implies it's linear (literally).)

Comment: what do you mean by "bilinear"?

Comment: For unfathomable reasons, some people call fractional linear transformations "bilinear" ([search](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=bilinear+transformation+[complex-analysis])). I wonder where that originates.

Comment: @DanielFischer, the spate of references to linear-fractional transformations as "bilinear" seems to have kicked up pretty recently, though: I don't think I'd seen any such reference prior to a week or two ago  (=early July 2015), and, since I am interested in some things related to such, I think I would have remembered any earlier episodes at all. But I see that you found some... Weird. Sorta obscures the meaning of "bilinear", for sure. What do they call bilinear maps, then? I don't understand this...

Comment: @DanielFischer People used to call them "linear". I suspect the reason is what happens if you identify $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ with the space of complex lines through the origin in $\mathbb C^2$. (Details in _Complex Made Simple_...)

Comment: I'd just like to note, for the record, that usually a "bilinear map" is a map $b:V\times W\to Z$ of vector spaces over a field $k$ which is linear in each argument separately. Seems to me un-necessary and unwise to subvert this very-standard, useful sense. Also, linear fractional transformations (also called "Mobius" transformations) were not ever called "linear", to my knowledge, in part because they are not literally linear ($f:V\to W$ of vector spaces satisfies $f(v+v')=f(v)+f(v')$, which few linear-fractional transformations do...)

Comment: @paulgarrett Have you looked in any _old_ references? I've _seen_ them called linear. See my comment to Daniel or buy the book for a very plausible reason why: A map from $\mathbb C_\infty$ to itself induces a map on projective space, which then induces a map from $\mathbb C^2$ to itself, which turns out to be literally linear if you started with a linear-fractional transformation.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, things descended from linear things, that are not linear, are not necessarily ... linear. I don't know what you mean by "old", but nothing I read from late 19th through 20th in the professional literature called linear-fractional "linear". I've heard no _person_ ever refer to them as such, in some decades of being in the math milieu. It is true that until maybe 1900 there was a not-so-clear sense of "linearity" in general, but, ...

Comment: @paulgarrett And then as a bonus: Composition of linear-fractional transformations becomes composition of the corresponding _linear_ transformations on $\mathbb C^2$, making it clear why composition of linear-fractional transformations is given by matrix multiplication.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, yes, indeed, and I say this to my students. But the linear fractional transformations are maps on a _quotient_, and are no longer literally linear. Sure, they're descended-to-the-quotient from linear maps, but... they simply aren't linear. If we decide to say that anything descended from a linear map, on a quotient, is called linear, then things will be rough, because we won't know any more whether it has the _properties_ of a linear map... only that some one of its ancestors did. A nastily unhelpful terminological choice, I think.

Comment: @paulgarrett Well of course not. I wasn't saying we should call them linear! People were wondering why other people called them "bilinear". I don't know, but it seemed like a plausible explanation of why they _were_ formerlly called "linear" might be relevant. (No, I've never heard a person call them linear.)

Comment: ... and I don't think the associativity of the action, etc., is a bonus of calling non-linear maps linear. It's a bonus of the fact that the non-linear maps are descended from linear maps, on a quotient.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, ah, sorry, I thought you were "defending", not "explaining". I suspect that the "bilinear" usage is just some "eggcorn" or whatever linguists call little semantic train-wrecks.

Comment: @paulgarrett Give me a break. How could anyone possibly suggest that a mathematical _fact_ followed from a curious bit of terminology?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, indeed. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett, see page 328 in https://books.google.com/books?id=SFqbV3i3hO0C&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=ablowitz+fokas+bilinear+transformations&source=bl&ots=fVw920LPpx&sig=XjHlHjbmRldOBsEf3euIPfLQD8c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBGoVChMI_PyKhvLvxgIVQyqICh3vNwL9#v=onepage&q=ablowitz%20fokas%20bilinear%20transformations&f=false

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich see page 328 https://books.google.com/books?id=SFqbV3i3hO0C&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=ablowitz+fokas+bilinear+transformations&source=bl&ots=fVw920LPpx&sig=XjHlHjbmRldOBsEf3euIPfLQD8c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBGoVChMI_PyKhvLvxgIVQyqICh3vNwL9#v=onepage&q=ablowitz%20fokas%20bilinear%20transformations&f=false

Comment: then pages 366ff

Comment: @WillJagy, ... argh... Can't call a spade a spade any more? Wow. If I were younger and spunkier (and more optimistic that there would be change for the better) I'd rant about this... sigh...

Comment: @paul, more to the point, ask the authors where they live so we can hunt them down

Comment: @WillJagy, :)....